# btrfs online conversion from directory to subvolume

Tags: linux, btrfs

Is there a way to create a btrfs subvolume from a directory, without interrupting processes using files in that directory.

For instance, I want to create a subvolume for `/tmp` (to exclude it from snapshots), and if possible, without stopping all programs having open files in `/tmp`.

Comment: check this answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212331/137741